# Angular app stuck at loading. (probably an @Input()-like error idk)

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Helo(+l),

I want to make a simple app which display posts. My problem is when i deploy the first page which display "Loading..." is stuck. Please help me, i'm sure it's nothing serious.

I have a post component, inside a post-list component, inside app component. I have also made a post-service :

post-list component html :

```html
<h2>Posts</h2>
<ul class="list-group">
  <app-post-list  *ngFor="let post of posts; let i = index"
                 [postTitle]="post.titre"
                 [postContent]="post.content"
                 [postLikes]="post.loveIts" 
                 [postDate]="post.created_at"
                 [index]="i"
                 [id]="post.id"></app-post-list>
</ul>
```

post-list.ts :

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Input } from '@angular/core';
import { PostService } from '../services/post.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-post-list',
  templateUrl: './post-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post-list.component.scss']
})
export class PostListComponent implements OnInit {
  
  posts: any[];
  @Input() id: number;
  
  constructor(private postService: PostService) { }
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.posts = this.postService.posts;
  }
}
```

post.html :

```html
<li [ngClass]="{'list-group-item': true,
'list-group-item-success': postTitle === 'lol',
'list-group-item-danger': postTitle === 'lol'}">

<h4 [ngStyle]="{color: getColor()}">{{ postTitle }}</h4>
<p>{{ postDate | date:short}}</p>
 
<p>{{ postContent }}</p>
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-success"(click)="like()">J'aime</button>
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"(click)="dislike()">Je n'aime pas</button>
</li>
```

post.ts :

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { PostService } from '../services/post.service'


@Component({
  selector: 'app-post',
  templateUrl: './post.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post.component.scss']
})
export class PostComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() postTitle: string;
  @Input() postContent: string;
  @Input() postLikes: number;
  @Input() postDate: Date;
  @Input() id: number;
  @Input() index: number;

  constructor(private postService: PostService) { }

  ngOnInit() {}

  getColor() {
    if(this.postLikes > +0) {
      return 'green';
    } else if(this.postLikes < +0) {
      return 'red';
    }else {
      return 'gray';
    }
  }

  like(){
      this.postService.like(this.index);
  }

  dislike(){
    this.postService.dislike(this.index);
  }
}
```

post.service :

```js
import { Post } from '../class/post';

export class PostService {
    private post1: Post;
    private post2: Post;
    private post3: Post;

    posts = [this.post1, this.post2, this.post3];
    
    constructor(){
        this.post1 = new Post();
        this.post1.setTitre("Pourquoi la poule traverse la route ?");
        this.post1.setloveIts(10);
        this.post1.setContent("Le fait que ce soit le poulet qui traverse la route ou que ce soit la route qui se meuve sous le poulet dépend uniquement de votre référentiel. Les poulets, au travers de longues périodes, ont été naturellement sélectionnés de telle sorte qu'ils soient génétiquement enclins à traverser les routes. La troisième loi des Poulets énonce qu'un poulet doit protéger sa propre existence sauf si cette protection le force à désobéir à un ordre humain ou à blesser un humain.")
        this.post1.setIndex(1);

        this.post2 = new Post();
        this.post2.setTitre("Allo ? A l'Huile !");
        this.post2.setloveIts(-40);
        this.post2.setContent("Hue hue hue");
        this.post2.setIndex(2);

        this.post3 = new Post();
        this.post3.setTitre("Parce que la forme est contraignante, l'idée jaillit plus intense !");
        this.post3.setloveIts(50);
        this.post3.setContent("L'un des exemples les plus célèbres de contrainte dans le domaine littéraire est La Disparition (1969) de Georges Perec, qui ne comporte pas la lettre e. Un autre exemple est celui de l'auteur britannique Christine Brooke-Rose dans Remake (1996), qui ne comporte pas la lettre t, et Between (1968), qui ne contient pas le verbe to be (être).");
        this.post3.setIndex(3);
    }
    
    like(i: number) {
        this.posts[i].incrementeLoveIts();
    }
    
    dislike(i: number) {
        this.posts[i].decrementeLoveIts();
    }

    getPostsById(id: number) {
        const post = this.posts.find(
          (s) => {
            return s.getIndex() === id;
          }
        );
        return post;
    }
}
```

EDIT :

StackTrace :

```html
Stacktrace : 
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'postTitle' since it isn't a known property of 'app-post-list'.
1. If 'app-post-list' is an Angular component and it has 'postTitle' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-post-list' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("ul class="list-group">
  <app-post-list  *ngFor="let post of posts; let i = index"
                 [ERROR ->][postTitle]="post.titre"
                 [postContent]="post.content"
                 [postLikes]=""): ng:///AppModule/PostListComponent.html@3:17
```

I think in post-list.html component i made an irregular reference to the other component

Comment: `[postTitle]="post.titre"` <- title?

Comment: What error are you getting in the console? If you're in chrome, press F12 and check the console tab. What does your post class look like?

Comment: can you provide a stackblitz ?

Comment: Gijs Post : My class Post have a property named "titre" so no.

Comment: didn't you forget to declare/inject it into your module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was indeed that. in post-list.html i was referencing `<app-post-list></>` instead of `<app-post></>`.

Thank you all